# How to use ForkOptions in SBT to change working directory for test within subproject?

Tags: scala, sbt

I currently have a multiproject SBT build with 2 projects under it, one of which has a dependency on the other. The dependent one has a test in which it needs to load a file from a certain directory structure underneath its working directory. It uses a relative path in a configuration file to designate this directory structure.

The issue is that depending on whether I am running this test through my IDE (with working directory at the subproject level) or at the SBT umbrella project level (with working directory at the umbrella level) makes a difference in the ability of my test to load this file via its relative path and succeed.

I need to use a relative path so that other developers working on this project may use the checked-in code out of the box, and duplicating the directory structure and contained files at two levels in the project is out of the question. What I really need to do is direct SBT to move the working directory into the subproject when doing tests, so that the directory structure can remain the same regardless of where the test is initiated from.

SBT offers a ForkOptions class (http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.13.0/api/index.html#sbt.ForkOptions), further described here: http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.13/docs/Forking.html at the bottom of the page, through which it seems one can supply a working directory for the forked JVM to be started in but gives no good examples on how to set up the configuration in a root build.sbt or supply a ForkOptions instance to a test task.

Does anyone have any experience using this class, and/or can anyone offer some guidance on getting this functionality out of a multiproject build in SBT?

Comment: See also: https://github.com/sbt/sbt/issues/1032

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is to provide the following settings to the project definition in the root build.sbt.

```
lazy val yourProject = project.settings(
    fork := true,
    baseDirectory in test := file("yourProject")
)
```

These cause the JVM to fork for the tests in that subproject and changes the working directory to the base of that subproject.